# How can I aggregate data.table in quarterly frequency?

Tags: r, date, data.table, aggregate, frequency

My data is available in monthly frequency and I'm trying to aggregate them in quarterly frequency. I'm working with data.table which package I dont understand very well, to be honest.

```
   X.DATA_BASE                                             NOME_INSTITUICAO     SALDO.x    SALDO.y
1:      199407 ASB S/A - CFI                                                    1694581    1124580
2:      199407 BANCO ARAUCARIA S.A.                                            40079517    6314782
3:      199407 BANCO ATLANTIS S.A.                                            200463907    9356445
4:      199407 BANCO BANKPAR                                                    1078342    5770046
5:      199407 BANCO BBI                                                       97812975   31112289
```

For each date, which is defined by X.DATA_BASE, 199407 = July 1994. I have several institutions with SALDO.x and SALDO.y values. I want to add SALDO.x and SALDO.y for each institution in each quarterly. One of the problem is that some institutions get in and get out through the time. In the end of the day I want to have mydata with the same columns but quarterly frequency.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to group and sum by quarter (with thanks to @eddi for his suggested improvement). First let's create some fake date:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1485)
dat = data.table(date=rep(c(199401:199412,199501:199512),2),
             firm=rep(c("A","B"), each=24),
             value1=rnorm(48,1000,10),
             value2=rnorm(48,2000,100))

dat
```

> ```
>       date firm    value1   value2
>  1: 199401    A 1009.8620 2054.251
>  2: 199402    A 1009.7180 2124.202
>  3: 199403    A 1014.3421 1919.251
> ...
> 46: 199510    B  992.9961 2079.517
> 47: 199511    B  997.9147 1968.676
> 48: 199512    B 1002.5993 2006.231
> ```

Now, summarize by firm, year, and quarter. To do this, we create `year` and `quarter` grouping variables from `date` (we use integer division (`%/%`) to create the years and mod (`%%`) plus integer division to create the quarters), and calculate the sum of `value1` and `value2` for each sub-group. This all assumes `date` is numeric. If you have it stored as character or factor, convert to numeric first:

```
dat.summary = dat[ , list(valueByQuarter = sum(sum(value1) + sum(value2))), 
              by=list(firm, 
                      year=date %/% 100, 
                      quarter=(date %% 100 - 1) %/% 3 + 1)]

dat.summary
```

> ```
>     firm year quarter valueByQuarter
>  1:    A 1994       1       9131.626
>  2:    A 1994       2       8953.116
>  3:    A 1994       3       8981.407
>  4:    A 1994       4       9175.959
>  5:    A 1995       1       9003.225
>  6:    A 1995       2       8962.690
>  7:    A 1995       3       8809.256
>  8:    A 1995       4       8885.264
>  9:    B 1994       1       9000.791
> 10:    B 1994       2       8936.356
> 11:    B 1994       3       8905.789
> 12:    B 1994       4       8951.369
> 13:    B 1995       1       8922.716
> 14:    B 1995       2       9097.134
> 15:    B 1995       3       8724.188
> 16:    B 1995       4       9047.934
> ```

For `dplyr` fans, here's a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(firm, year=date %/% 100, 
           quarter=(date %% 100 - 1) %/% 3 + 1) %>%
  summarise(valueByQuarter = sum(value1 + value2))
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!